# Dev-C++: Hello World Fails to Compile - Error on Make

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I am having lots of trouble getting a hello world program to compile in Dev-C++. I am very familiar with coding, I have been using python, C#, and Java for a few years now.

Syntax, and headers all seem to be fine. I have reinstalled Dev-C++ multiple times and have even tried installing the compiler manually to no avail. I have searched stack overflow and forums but still can't resolve my issue. I'm on windows 10.

Here is my code + compile error. It seems to fail on make.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

#Compile Log:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Dev-Cpp\Projects\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Dev-Cpp\Projects\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c project2.cpp -o project2.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"   

make.exe: *** [project2.o] Error -1073741674

Execution terminated
```

Thanks for the help, this is starting to get stressful.

Comment: I would recommend saving yourself a lot of future headaches by not using Dev C++. It is old and out of date, and doesn't look like it will ever be updated again.

Comment: I would love to but I'm in college and my professor made it clear that all exams would be using dev-c++ and that we must use it. I will email him and let him know of my problem but colleges don't like to make comprises. I think it's strange that they would force students to use outdated IDEs as well.

Comment: Can you pass options in dev c++ and maybe try to figure out which g++ version it uses? And try to enforce something like `-std=c++14` (or 17 or whatever, depending on *how* horribly outdated g++ is). Also try to find out what "Error -1073741674" means.

Comment: That error code means `STATUS_PRIVILEGED_INSTRUCTION` (do 2^32-1073741674 and convert to hex, which gives 0xC0000096, and google for `#define 0xC0000096`) which would indicate that g++ crashed hard and executed a bad jump instruction. (Because the error actually means an instruction like `mov cr0, eax` was executed which is only allowed in kernel mode, and g++ won't do that in normal circumstances hence I think it jumped into data/stack and executed random code, i.e. it crashed). - Probably it's a very old version that has a bug or an incompatibility issue with Win10 or some library.

Comment: I think I can pass parameters to the compiler. I will give `-std=c++14` a try and report back. Just Trued it and it didn't work. This is what Dev-C++ converted it to. `g++.exe -c project2.cpp -o project2.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"    -std=c++14`

Comment: I talked to my instructor and said I can use another IDE as long as Dev runs it fine on his computer. That should solve it. Thanks for the help everybody.

Comment: Crispy, You ain't seen nothing yet. We routinely get questions from students pertaining to TurboC++ (though I gotta say that's slowed down a lot this year) a C++ compiler from thirty <expletive deleted>ing years ago.

Comment: I know there is no answer, buy WHY?

Comment: Costs time and money to update a syllabus. This is why you will learn C++ from lessons adapted to C from Pascal. My recommendation is to get a good, up-to-date C++ programming text to use as a supplement so you get fewer surprises when you hit the workforce and find you learned C with `cout`.

Comment: Side note: Also find out what C++ Standard the instructor wants you to compile to. That way you should be able to stay up -to-date with your compiler tools and then slap on a command line option (`-std=c++XX` for the GCC family) to make sure you don't accidentally use `<filesystem>`, modules, or anything too cutting edge for the professor's compiler (probably GCC 4.something)

Comment: @user4581301 Lol thanks for all the help. It's funny that stackoverflow can teach me more in depth than a paid course at a college that results in a degree founded on outdated information. Have to get that degree though to make my family proud, and to make a "good" impression in society. I'm going back to Visual Studio, a true multi language IDE.

Comment: After programming professionally for several years in C and Java, I took advantage of unemployment in the aftermath of the [dot crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-com_bubble) and finished a more useful degree than Political Philosophy. More than doubled my wages for the exact same job. Annoying, but worth the time and money spent. I'm not a big fan of multi-language IDEs. They have a tendency to be really good at the language they were written in and no so good at the other languages they support.  Visual Studio's an outlier though. Now that it's Standard-compliant, it's pretty good.

Comment: The only multi language IDE i have ever used is Visual Studio, otherwise I agree a language specific IDE should be used. I use Eclipse for Java and WingIDE for python and Sublime Text for python when I want to feel cool.

Comment: Dev-C++ is not fully compliant with C++11, that's how out-of-date it is.

Comment: @Crispy have you tried creating a new `source file` instead of creating a `project`?

Comment: I got the exact same issue with Dev-C++ 4.9.9. Just turn to Embarcadero's fork that officially supports Windows 10: https://sourceforge.net/projects/embarcadero-devcpp/